# How can I remove an bgimage in Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

I imported an bg image like so

```
screen = turtle.Screen()


#reference image
screen.bgpic("image.png")
```

then I made my graphic but I want to remove the bg image so only the bgcolor remains and if I `screen.clear()` it clears everything I drew with turtle.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, pass `'nopic'` as the `picname` argument and it will remove the current image:

```
bgpic(picname=None)
    Set background image or return name of current backgroundimage.
    
    Optional argument:
    picname -- a string, name of a gif-file or "nopic".
    
    If picname is a filename, set the corresponding image as background.
    If picname is "nopic", delete backgroundimage, if present.
    If picname is None, return the filename of the current backgroundimage.
```

The `'nopic'` token is also returned when interrogating `bgpic()` if there is no background image set:

```
% python3
Python 3.8.3 (v3.8.3:6f8c8320e9, May 13 2020, 16:29:34) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
>>> turtle.bgpic()
'nopic'
>>>
```